# After install of ubuntu fails to load

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu and everything works fine. I can get on internet. But once I turn off my computer and turn in back on it gives me

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 201583/15204352 files, 2295554/60790016 blocks
```

But nothing else, what can I do to fix the problem? Please help

Comment: How do you turn off your computer? If this happens (almost) every time, I'd guess that 1) something in the shut down procedure fails to unmount the file system correctly or 2) there is no shut down procedure because you just flip the switch or cut the power instead of instructing Ubuntu to shut down the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you end up with a non-responding system, you could do the following to get past the file check:

1. Reboot the system in recovery mode, [see help page on recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)  or boot with a live USB/DVD
2. Check and repair the sda1 file system see [page on filesystem check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting). Basically run `fsck -p -C0 /dev/sda1`
3. Reboot normally and see if the console passes

If it still hangs, it might be another cause. I have seen it in virtualbox when Ubuntu is updated but I forgot to update the vbox drivers. If you are on virtualbox and this is indeed your first install, I would re-install, update the system and than update the vbox extension pack before rebooting. Afterwards you can hold shift and select an older kernel to boot and update.

Otherwise we would need more details...